# CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED and now laptop only boots into BIOS. No boot options found

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, asus-laptop

Last week I had a problem with my ASUS laptop and I decided to come here in hopes that you wonderful people might be able to help me.

I was working normally when out of nowhere I got a CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED BSOD with the usual Windows 8 message "Your PC ran into a problem .... We're just collecting some error information..." and the counter was stuck a 0%. After waiting a while and no progress I decided to press the power button and reset it. After that, the laptop can no longer boot into windows. It boots directly into the BIOS menu and there's little I can do from there.

The laptop has a 128 GB SSD with Windows 8 pre-installed in it and a HHD where I keep all my personal files. The HDD is absolutely fine and I have managed to back up everything but the SSD seems unresponsive. It appears in the SATA configuration menu in the BIOS but if I try to access the BIOS Boot Options the only thing that appears there is the DVD drive or a USB device if I have one connected.

I sent it over to a repair shop and they told they would try to recondition the SSD drive and restore the laptop to factory settings. I think they ran an analysis first and told me the SSD is unusable and it would cost nearly £300 to replace it. For that money and because the laptop is still in warranty I decided not to go ahead with the repair. If I have to I'll send it over to ASUS directly and hope a replacement is covered by the warranty. But because that will take time and I need my laptop urgently I decided to turn to this forum for now and hope there is something I can try and do to fix it.

I've tried accessing the restore to factory settings menu by pressing F9 repeatedly, or pressing and holding, but it still goes straight into the BIOS.

UPDATE: Using a Windows installation disk (not the original one) I was able to access the Command Prompt and run a Disk Analysis. No problems were found or fixed.

Here's some details about the laptop:

- Make and version: ASUS N551-JK
- OS: Windows 8.1 64-bit (Pre-Installed)
- Storage: 128 SSD (OS) and 500 GB HHD
- RAM: 12 GB

Does anyone have any suggestions for solving this? Let me know if you need more information and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you wiped the wrong partition. Even if that's not the case, find your Windows Repair disc that came with the laptop. Since it was pre-installed, the computer most likely came with the disc. Insert the disc into the CD drive and go to bios and change the boot to your CD Drive. Boot to the disc and there should be some options to fix or re-install Windows completely.

Best of luck,
Bryce.

Let me know if this fixes the problem!

Comment: Unfortunately the laptop didn't come with an installation disk nor did I make a system restore disk when I had the chance. I'm regretting it now.

Comment: Hmmm... Have another computer?

Comment: I do. My housemate lent me one but it's a different make with a different version of Windows.

Comment: It does not matter. You can still use his laptop to burn a new disc with Windows on it, or you can just use his recovery disc to fix yours (even if outdated)

Comment: I'll give that a try then. I don't have any disks handy but tomorrow I'll go buy one and try doing that. Will report back with the results :) Thank you

Comment: Oh yeah, btw make sure your friend's computer can burn discs. If it can't then, I don't know what to do. Best of luck, I'll be here

Comment: @Wolfsmash We frown against asking people to accept our own answers.  If you have a problem with this comment contact a moderator in chat or on Meta.superuser, my only goal with this comment, is to see better more complete answers

Comment: @Wolfsmash I have used the spare laptop to create a recovery disk. When I try to use it on my laptop I get a Toshiba Recovery Wizard menu. If I choose the repair option I get an error telling me the version of Windows is not compatible with the existing one. I also have the option of installing windows which I haven't tried because I don't think that is something I'd want to do.